# How to fix "gcloud crashed" when any gcloud command is executed in Google Cloud SDK Shell?

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-cloud-platform

Well, at the work we have a client who has his project in Google Cloud Platform, so I need to use Google Cloud SDK commands to clone the repository to my PC and do some other configurations, but first I have problems Installing Google Cloud SDK because this error appear when installation was about to be completed. However, I could solve it, but now i have this issue in the command prompt. The same error and same code, just different place.

I'm using Python 2.7.15 for this software and I'm not very familiar with Python, so I search this problem on google an there are a lot of solutions but none has been useful, but all of it says this is a Python Exception. The code of the byte is `0xed` and none of the other forums or posts has this byte in this error. Similar error, but not the same byte code and it seems like not same solution. I have tried whit Python 2.7.0 and that version does not let me install it, after whit Python 2.7.5 and the problem is the same as in the current versión (2.7.15)

> ERROR: gcloud crashed (CommandLoadFailure): Problem loading gcloud.compute: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 15: ordinal not in range(128).
>
> If you would like to report this issue, please run the following command:
>     gcloud feedback
>
> To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following command:
>     gcloud info --run-diagnostics

I just want to run the commands of Google Cloud SDK free of this error, and, if it's possible free for all type of errors at the end.

Comment: Also OS Version

Comment: Hi, the version of OS is W10, and I have not written code for this issue, I just installed python and Google Cloud SDK, thsi problem appear with all gclud command, as if Google Cloud SDK was not installed

Comment: Edit your question and add the output from `pip freeze`. Also, add the stacktrace for the error. My guess is that you either have another module that conflicts with the Cloud SDK (two different Python modules with the same name) or you have a corrupted Python environment.

Comment: Thank you all, the problem was my User Name in my PC. It has NON ASCII character's: "Benjamín Ramírez" please have it in count if you want to intall Cloud SDK. Do not make your PC Profile/username with non ascii character's like '´'.